# Reverse proxy header should be provided

Tags: node.js, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I use reverse proxy from the following module in node app-:

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

My question is whether I need to modify the header for state of reverse proxy to work like standard?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

According to my basic understand, you need to use additional headers in order to pass information to the origin server.

try :

```
X-Forwarded-For  //The IP address of the client.
X-Forwarded-Host //The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
X-Forwarded-Server //The hostname of the proxy server.
```

this info is based on [This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers)